# Display the fruits bought by particular student with respective price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

There are different names who have bought different fruits. I need the Person name and the different fruits he has bought with the price displayed

This is the sample input

```
NAME    FRUIT     PRICE
akshay  apple       10
ashish  orange      20
vaibhav pinapple    30
nagesh  guava       10
akshay  guava       10
akshay  pinapple    30
ashish  pinapple    30
vaibhav apple       10
nagesh  guava       10
```

The person has bought different fruits I need to display it without repeating the name of the person

Sample Output

```
NAME    FRUIT    PRICE
akshay  apple    10
        guava    10
        pinapple 30
ashish  orange   20
        pinapple 30
vaibhav pinapple 30
        apple    10
nagesh  guava    10
```

The fruit must be grouped by the name

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns and for replace duplicated values to empty strings add [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) + [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['NAME','FRUIT']).reset_index(drop=True)
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].mask(df['NAME'].duplicated(), '')
print (df)
      NAME     FRUIT  PRICE
0   akshay     apple     10
1              guava     10
2           pinapple     30
3   ashish    orange     20
4           pinapple     30
5   nagesh     guava     10
6              guava     10
7  vaibhav     apple     10
8           pinapple     30
```

Another possible way for displaying is create `MutliIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['NAME','FRUIT']).sort_index()
print (df)
                  PRICE
NAME    FRUIT          
akshay  apple        10
        guava        10
        pinapple     30
ashish  orange       20
        pinapple     30
nagesh  guava        10
        guava        10
vaibhav apple        10
        pinapple     30
```